# Psychic Sight and Permanent Detect Psionics

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats, psionics

If I pick up the [*Psychic Sight*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20070629a) feat and manifest [*Incarnate*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/incarnate.htm) to gain a permanent *Detect Psionics* effect, do I also permanently gain the effects of *Arcane Sight*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When you have Psychic Sight, once per day you can expend your psionic focus when manifesting *detect psioinics* to manifest *arcane sight* (well, its “psionic equivalent” anyway) as well. At that point, you have two separate effects on you, one *detect psionics* and the other *arcane sight*. They are independent of one another, and the *arcane sight* will last 1 minute/level, even if you stop concentrating on the *detect psionics* effect. Likewise, while you can manifest *incarnate* on the *detect psionics* and cause it to become permanent, the *arcane sight* effect will **still** last 1 minute/level. Nothing in the feat description ties the duration of the *arcane sight* effect to the duration of the *detect psionics* effect.

On the other hand, *arcane sight* is a valid target for *permanency*, so its “psionic equivalent” is presumably a valid target for *incarnate*. This would presumably cost the same 1,500 XP and require the same 11th level as *permanency* does for *arcane sight*. But Mind’s Eye neglects to spell this out, so you’ll have to double-check exactly what “psionic equivalent” really means; that’s not a defined term in the rules.

For that matter, it’s not really clear that this psionic *arcane sight* is actually being manifested as a psionic power. It just says you “gain” it. If this is, say, a psi-like or supernatural effect, then it won’t be a valid target for *incarnate*.

Comment: It says the equivalent of a spell. Would that not mean it's being gained as a psionic power effect?

Comment: @Cellheim That seems the most reasonable interpretation of the words they used, but the words they used are fundamentally *not actually defined anywhere in the rules*. I don’t know for sure what “gaining” the “psionic equivalent” of a spell actually means, I can only guess, because those are not the usual or correct terminology for how things get done under the rules.

Comment: And a shame it is that they didn't bother to define some of the terms they used.